# i must write command lines but can not find cmd

Tags: shell

I have searched for the language packs and extensions and there is a way that we must write command lines, where i must write them? I'm working on cpanel to customize my website

Comment: Sorry,donot understood the  your  point.Could you please explain?

Comment: i'm new in this domain (web) , and i don't know how to use extensions in magento..

Answer (score 0):

You have to have the ssh access with the appropriate read/write/execute permissions to the server to work in command prompt.

Comment: how could i have the permission?

Comment: You have to raise a support ticket to the hosting provider to get the SSH access you are having permission for that. Else, you have to request the client to raise the ticket for you.

Comment: is there any way to install language package on magento 2 without using command lines?

Comment: Can you try with this?https://www.scriptinstallation.in/installing_language_cpanel.html